# Verify OAuth 2.0 token

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, jwt, openid

I have a token from Microsoft OAuth 2.0 with PKCE that in is sent to my Django server from a front-end. How can I verify the integrity of this token? I want to allow users to sign in with their Microsoft accounts.

Comment: I don't understand how my question "includes multiple questions in one". There is only one question: "How to verify the integrity of the token?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to verify the integrity of the token? You could just attempt to log the user in. If it works, the token is good.

#### Edits

- I would check the [Microsoft Docs: OAuth and Open ID Connect Protocols](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols) for help on logging a user in.
- Maybe it's possible to attempt to renew the token as a quick and dirty way of testing during development.
  [Microsoft API Docs: Use a token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#use-a-token)

Comment: Thank you. Can you clarify what you mean by "log the user in"? To which URL should I send the token to verify it? I have to verify it somehow otherwise a malicious user could just claim to be signed into an email address.

Comment: Edited my answer above with some links that I think will be helpful :)